# Joining 3 tables on 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created 3 views with identical columns- Quantity, Year, and Variety. I want to join all three tables on year and variety in order to do some calculations with quantities.

The problem is that a particular year/variety combo does not occur on every view.

I've tried queries like :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
a
    left outer join
b
    on a.variety = b.variety
    left outer join
c
    on a.variety = c.variety or b.variety = c.variety
WHERE
    a.year = '2015'
    and b.year = '2015'
    and a.year= '2015'
```

Obviously this isn't the right solution. Ideally I'd like to join on both year and variety and not use a where statement at all.

The desired output would be put all quantities of matching year and variety on the same line, regardless of null values on a table.

I really appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a full outer join, not a left join, like so:

```
Select coalesce(a.year, b.year, c.year) as Year
  , coalesce(a.variety, b.variety, c.variety) as Variety
  , a.Quantity, b.Quantity, c.Quantity
from tableA a
full outer join tableB b
  on a.variety = b.variety 
  and a.year = b.year
full outer join tableC c
  on isnull(a.variety, b.variety) = c.variety
  and isnull(a.year, b.year) = c.year
where coalesce(a.year, b.year, c.year) = 2015
```

The left join you are using won't pick up values from b or c that aren't in a.  Additionally, your where clause is dropping rows that don't have values in all three tables (because the year in those rows is null, which is not equal to 2015).  The full outer join will grab rows from either table in the join, regardless of whether the other table contains a match.

Comment: you are a lifesaver. worked all morning putting the views together and felt like my face was melting. thank you!